# CSS: Hovering over child of element should affect different element

Tags: html, css

I want users to be able to `hover` over a `button` within a different `div`, which then changed the `background-color` of the `div` below.

My current code is as followed:

```css
.delSeperator button:hover+.linkField {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.seperator {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #e4e8eb;
  min-height: 0.5rem;
  margin: 1rem 0rem 1rem 0rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="delSeperator_0" class="row delSeperator">
  <div class="col-xs-10 mb-0">
    <div class='seperator vertical-center'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 mb-0"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delField('linkField', this.closest('.row')); delField('delSeperator', this.closest('.row'));"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>
</div>

<div class="row linkField" id="linkField_0">
  <div class="col-xs-6 mb-0">
    <div class="form-group"><label for="txt_link[0][&quot;bezeichnung&quot;]" class="">Bezeichnung</label><input id="txt_link[0][&quot;bezeichnung&quot;]" type="text" maxlength="200" name="link[0][&quot;bezeichnung&quot;]" class="form-control"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 mb-0">
    <div class="form-group"><label for="txt_link[0][&quot;url&quot;]" class="">URL</label><input id="txt_link[0][&quot;url&quot;]" type="url" maxlength="500" name="link[0][&quot;url&quot;]" class="form-control"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Changing the Hover-CSS to

```
.delSeperator:hover + .linkField {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}
```

works so that when you hover over the whole `.delSeperator`, the `.linkField` gets the background property.

When I change the code to

```
.delSeperator button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}
```

it works so that when you `hover` over the `button`, the `button` gets the `background` property.

But I can't seem to combine these two. Is there any way to achieve what I need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to affect other elements when one element is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered)

Comment: @SecretTimes Unfortunately no, since as you can see I already tried the answer on the link provided and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can workaround this issue by playing with the `pointer-events` property

i got this to work with the following CSS:

```
.delSeperator:hover + .linkField {
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}

.delSeperator {
  pointer-events: none
}

.delSeperator button {
  pointer-events: initial
}
```